# Java bugs for Mac site

Tags: java, macos

Is there an official site where I can see all the java bugs for the mac?

Edit: I want to check if an error I'm having is a known issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So Apple bugs are always private: you have no idea if someone else has filed your bug.

There's a solution by some of the Mac Developer community: [OpenRadar](http://www.openradar.appspot.com)

Answer (score 3):

Java on OSX is developed  by Apple it self, so the main site will be the Apple Developer Connection

Start here: http://developer.apple.com/java/

**EDIT**

I've been looking for those at that site and what I found was the link for you to reporte your own bug. A ADC account is needed ( which I don't really feel like creating now ) and from there you can access to the bug reported. Chances are that the existing bugs are listed there already.

Here's the link, I hope you find it useful:

http://developer.apple.com/support/mac/bugreports/

Answer (score 1):

A good number (most) of Java bugs are not Mac-specific, so you should always check [Sun's (Oracle's?) bug tracker](http://bugs.sun.com/) as well (first). I suppose people even report Mac-specific bugs there as well.